# Microsoft Graph API - The property 'subject' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm sending emails from my application users after they authorized access to their Outlook inbox.

The complete scope :

> a:9:{i:0;s:14:"Calendars.Read";i:1;s:19:"Calendars.ReadWrite";i:2;s:9:"Mail.Read";i:3;s:14:"Mail.ReadWrite";i:4;s:9:"Mail.Send";i:5;s:9:"User.Read";i:6;s:7:"profile";i:7;s:6:"openid";i:8;s:5:"email";}

Somehow, for 2 specifics users (I've never encountered this issue with other users) **with the same domain**, I get the following error :

> Client error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"The property 'subject' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'

But the `subject` does exist, according to the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0

Any idea why these specific users get this error ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a hybrid environment and are those mailboxes hosted OnPrem ? the ability to use graph against hybrid onPrem mailboxes has been depreciated as of March 2023 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support you need to switch to using EWS for any OnPrem access.